# What should I do for warning C26800?

Tags: c++-winrt

I have a method in a C++/WinRT component.
It produces the code analysis warning C26800.

The method is an async coroutine.
It returns an IAsyncOperation of a projected defined in a MIDL file.
It takes as a parameter an AudioGraph object which is a projected type from "Windows.Media.Audio.h".
The parameter is declared as "AudioGraph graph", not "AudioGraph const& graph" so that it is copied and not referenced.
But when I call a method on it, the code analysis reports a C26800 warning.

I can't figure what to do with this warning. Can I safely ignore it or should I change my code ?

Here is the code for the method :

```cpp
IAsyncOperation<CompositeInstrument> CompositeInstrument::LoadAsync(AudioGraph graph)
{
    MediaSource mediaSource{ MediaSource::CreateFromStream(waveStream, L"audio/x-wav") };
    // the following line produces warning C26800: Utilisation d'un objet déplacé : ''graph'' (lifetime.1)
    CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeResult result{ co_await graph.CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeAsync(mediaSource) };
    if (result.Status() != MediaSourceAudioInputNodeCreationStatus::Success)
    {
         // etc...
    }
    
    // etc...

    co_return compositeInstrument;
}
```

Comment: Which line of code generates [C26800](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26800)? Also, have you noticed, that [AudioGraph.CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audiograph.createmediasourceaudioinputnodeasync) takes its argument by const ref? I haven't verified whether this is a documentation bug or a code gen bug of cppwinrt.exe. Can you check what signature this function has on the generated `AudioGraph` projected type?

Comment: The "graph.CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeAsync(mediaSource)" creates the warning. The message is : "warning C26800: Utilisation d'un objet déplacé : ''waveStream'' (lifetime.1)" (sorry it's in french).

Comment: And for the method signature, the doc is here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audiograph.createmediasourceaudioinputnodeasync?view=winrt-19041. The signature is IAsyncOperation<CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeResult> CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeAsync(MediaSource const & mediaSource)

Comment: I think my code follows the recommendations listed here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency#parameter-passing

Comment: That's the signature from the documentation. Though what's the signature of your generated code? It should be under *Generated Files\\winrt*. And which version of C++/WinRT are you using?

Comment: Here is the signature : template <typename D> WINRT_IMPL_AUTO(Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<Windows::Media::Audio::CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeResult>) consume_Windows_Media_Audio_IAudioGraph3<D>::CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeAsync(Windows::Media::Core::MediaSource const& mediaSource) const

Comment: That's a bug, and the compiler's diagnostic is right on spot. There was an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/issues/388) way back in mid 2019 with cppwinrt.exe's code generation around async interfaces, though it has been fixed. What version of C++/WinRT are you using? The first comment line in each generated winrt header file should contain the version information.

Comment: The version in the generated headers is v2.0.201201.7 (last version). The version of my VSIX extension is also v2.0.201201.7. The version of the Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT nuget is also 2.0.201201.7... The issue in mid 2019 does not exactly looks like my problem...

Comment: That's using the latest release then. If you can put together a repro, you should file an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/new/choose) with the C++/WinRT team.

Comment: So my code is correct. Thanks ! I will try to file an issue. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as answer ?

Comment: Did you ever post that issue?

Comment: Yes, it was fixed in VS 16.10 : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/warning-c26800-false-positive/1286809

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Visual Studio.
It has been [fixed in VS 16.10](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/warning-c26800-false-positive/1286809).